# Unable to create directory in LINUX (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException)

Tags: java, linux, java.nio.file

I'm trying to make a job to automate the process of creating a folder.

I can make the job work on windows but not on Linux and the exception makes no doubt about the problem, but the directory in question this case would be **/path/to/dir/** has full permission.

I'm far from being an expert on Linux and/or OSs inner workings, but maybe it happens because the process running the jar has no permission? (Sorry if I'm saying something very stupid)

Much appreciated for your time.

```
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;

        logger.info("Démarrage de la création du répertoire PDF pour " + year);

        Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/dir/" + year);

        if (!Files.exists(path)) {

            Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");
            FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> fileAttributes = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(permissions);

            try {
                Files.createDirectory(path, fileAttributes);
                logger.info("La création du répertoire PDF a réussi");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création du répertoire PDF");
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            logger.info("Annuaire existant");
        }
    }
```

stack trace

```
sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84), 
sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102), 
sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107), 
sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider
.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:383), 
java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:630), 
java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:734), 
java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:720), 
project.winnew.xp.jobs.
CreatePdfFolderJob.execute(CreatePdfFolderJob.java:40), 
org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202), 
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the case but there might be problem with the slashes. I'd rather use `File.separator`.

Comment: Which file/path do you want to create? What is your working directory? do the problem still here if you execute as root (`sudo your_program`)

Comment: @Ecto - slash `/` is the _normal_ separator on *nix and should be fine. The more surprising part is `/` _also_ works on windows, even though _its_ usual separator is _back_slash ```\```

Comment: @Ecto its not from the slashes.

Comment: @Mathieu I'm providing the full path. (at least on Windows works as expected, from c:/)

Answer (score 0):

can you add the stack trace here, does user running this program has enough permissions to access the path mentioned.  try using createDirectories method instead.

Comment: I edited the question and added the stack trace. Also tried the createDirectories() the same result

Comment: "does user running this program has enough permissions to access the path mentioned" i will dive into this point tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

In the call stack I see this:

```
java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:720), 
project.winnew.xp.jobs.CreatePdfFolderJob.execute(CreatePdfFolderJob.java:40),
```

So, somewhere in the `CreatePdfFolderJob.execute()` there should be a call to `createDirectories()` (mind the plural), but your piece of code seem to call `createDirectory()` (mind the singular).

Are you sure you are looking at the right place in the code?

Comment: That was the last try suggested by @Sriram G

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder name, say `uploads` in your project's root directory, the path should be a string `"./uploads"`. Hence you can replace `"/path/to/dir/"` in your case with `"./uploads"`